# android list view failed to bind array

Tags: android, android-listview

Each listView binding tutorial I checked but I have a strong confusion in the adapter section.
First see my code

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
  "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
  "Linux", "OS/2" };

// First paramenter - Context
// Second parameter - Layout for the row
// Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
// Forth - the Array of data
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

// Assign adapter to ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

See this line

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

What is this? `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` who says that we can refer to the `listeView` by **R**???

why??? Please help

Comment: Even the simplest array binding to listview is not working. please help

Comment: Post simple_list_item_1.xml. You should have there a textview with id `text1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

try using

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

or use

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.theTextViewID, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs:

> public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
>
> Parameters
>
> context    The current context.
>
> resource   The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when 
>   instantiating views.
>
> textViewResourceId The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated
>
> objects    The objects to represent in the ListView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, T[])

You should have in the layout file simple_list_item_1.xml a textview with id `text1`.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code....

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
```

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);